# I can't rollback a Docker netcore application to normal Linux Web Application in Azure

Tags: azure, docker, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have a Netcore application previously running under docker, but I can't rollback it to publish it in Azure as a normal Linux Web Application without Docker container. I have created a new Web App in Azure without support to Docker.

I have removed my docker file from the project, I have removed any reference to docker in my project, however when I publish it in Azure the application doesn't start, it displays this error below, it seems still trying to run in Docker container:

:( Application Error
If you are the application administrator, you can access the diagnostic resources.

In the Azure log, I can notice that Azure is starting the container, regardless no reference existing in my application anymore.

```
2021-10-14T14:49:04.146Z INFO  - Stopping site app-doc-manager-vdc-stage because it failed during startup.
2021-10-14T14:57:37.762Z INFO  - Starting container for site
2021-10-14T14:57:37.764Z INFO  - docker run -d -p 3589:8080 --name app-doc-manager-vdc-stage_0_26db5139 -e WEBSITE_SITE_NAME=app-doc-manager-vdc-stage -e WEBSITE_AUTH_ENABLED=False -e WEBSITE_ROLE_INSTANCE_ID=0 -e WEBSITE_HOSTNAME=app-doc-manager-vdc-stage.azurewebsites.net -e WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID=bfbdbaf98ea426a19b0a6118fa459879bbb220f8fd42b14234abdbd2cf0a0093 appsvc/dotnetcore:5.0_20210607.3 dotnet Unistad Document Manager.dll
```

Why Azure is starting the Docker container?

Another error I can notice in the log file is this one :

```
2021-10-14T14:57:46.572882489Z Running user provided startup command...
2021-10-14T14:57:46.644260885Z Could not execute because the application was not found or a compatible .NET SDK is not installed.
2021-10-14T14:57:46.645051197Z Possible reasons for this include:
2021-10-14T14:57:46.645062497Z   * You intended to execute a .NET program:
2021-10-14T14:57:46.645067297Z       The application 'Unistad' does not exist.
2021-10-14T14:57:46.645071497Z   * You intended to execute a .NET SDK command:
2021-10-14T14:57:46.645077197Z       It was not possible to find any installed .NET SDKs.
2021-10-14T14:57:46.645081497Z       Install a .NET SDK from:
2021-10-14T14:57:46.645085597Z         https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

Comment: Azure webapp is running in sandbox env, and it was originally running in docker. Azure webapp also support custom docler container.

Comment: If you have deployed webapp successfully, then you can try to add `Startup Command` to start your webapp. Like `dotnet project_name.dll` .

Comment: Thanks, it draw my attention that my project has spaces, so  Linux doesn't like spaces in file names.

Answer (score 0):

Following the recommendation mentioned by Jason Pan. I noticed my project name has spaces, so I changed the Start up command at Configuration -> General Settings from Document Manager.dll to Document\ Manager.dll, so Linux was able to manage the file name with spaces.
[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I added the image.